# Create deepcopy of dictionary without importing copy

Tags: python

How can i create a deepcopy of a dictinoary without importing the deepcopy module?
eg:

```
     dict = {'A' : 'can' , 'B' : 'Flower' , 'C' : 'house'}
```

I've tried assigning keys and values to 2 different lists and then creating a new dictionary with those values but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you want to import `copy`?

Comment: I want to create a project with no imports

Comment: @NicholasEvans I can understand this, but this is contrary to the Python philosophy.

Comment: This is why I asked "Why?" A question he did not answer properly yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your example does not require `deepcopy` as it does not have any nested `dict`s. For a *shallow* copy, you can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> dict1 = {'A' : 'can' , 'B' : 'Flower' , 'C' : 'house'}
>>> dict2 = {key: value for key, value in dict1.items()}
>>> dict2
{'A': 'can', 'C': 'house', 'B': 'Flower'}
```

---

However this method will **not** accomplish a deepcopy:

```
>>> dict1 = {'A' : []}
>>> dict2 = {key: value for key, value in dict1.items()}
>>> dict2['A'].append(5)
>>> dict1['A']
[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer from [Selcuk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40456947/7051394), you could simply do:

```
    dict1 = {'A': 'can', 'B': 'Flower', 'C': 'house'}
    dict2 = {}
    for key in dict1 :
        dict2[key] = dict1[key]
```

However, this example is pretty trivial, and if you happened to have objects instead of strings, you would have to re-implement a `deepcopy` function by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using strings, which are immutable and therefore shouldn't need to be copied.  So **a deep copy probably isn't more useful than a shallow copy in your situation**.

Here are two ways to do a **shallow copy**.

One way to copy a dictionary is to use its copy method:

```
my_dict = {'A' : 'can' , 'B' : 'Flower' , 'C' : 'house'}
another_dict = my_dict.copy()
```

Another is to pass the dictionary into the `dict` constructor:

```
my_dict = {'A' : 'can' , 'B' : 'Flower' , 'C' : 'house'}
another_dict = dict(my_dict)
```

You could also use a dictionary comprehension, but that's essentially the same thing using the `dict` constructor in many more characters.

Comment: Last time I checked, `dict.copy()` is a shallow copy.

Comment: You're correct. `dict` also does a shallow copy. I should have made more clear in my answer that I was saying "you don't need a deep copy in this particular circumstance". I'll highlight that.