# Python Class: Copying an object (Deep copy without importing copy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I would like to build a method that creates fully independent copy of an object with a different memory address(Deep copy). so that the old object's values won't be affected by the value changes of the new one.

Rather than using 'import copy', I would like to do it manually by defining a new method within the class.

say, I've been constructing a new class called 'student' and created an object 'eden'

```
class student:

    def __init__(self, name, year, number):
        self.name = name
        self.year = year
        self.number = number
        self.grades = []

    def new_num(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def update_grades(self, grades):
        self.grades.append(grades)

    def create_copy(self): ### this is what I want to create
        copy = student(self.name, self.year, self.number)
        return copy

eden = student('eden', 2, 12345)

#update new grades of eden
eden.update_grades(100)
eden.update_grades(90)
eden.update_grades(80)
eden.update_grades(95)

new_eden = eden.create_copy() #created a new object, new_eden
new_eden.new_num(54321) #change a value

print(eden is new_eden) #False

print(eden.grades) #[100, 90, 80, 95]
print(new_eden.grades) #[]
```

Although it seems like I managed to create a copy of an object with a different id, it showes that one instance variable, self.grade hasn't been copied to a new object. I would want to know how to copy all data same as the old one. (In this case, I've missed self.grades) Thank you in advance :)

Comment: `copy.grades = list(self.grades)` in `create_copy`

Comment: @khelwood: Or `copy.grades = self.grades.copy()` or `copy.grade = self.grades[:]`, just for completeness. In all cases it's only a shallow copy, but if `grades` is storing immutable types like `int`s or `float`s, that's fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create deepcopy of dictionary without importing copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456923/create-deepcopy-of-dictionary-without-importing-copy)